# Adding cloth physics to vertex group

Tags: mesh, physics, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I was wondering how to apply cloth physics to this cape vertex group. I do not need cloth physics on the rest of the mesh. The cape is apart of the mesh and is not separate. Any help is appreciated.

Updated: The main goal of the wind simulation is to test the cloth simulation of the cape. I have done both a cloth simulation, which yielded no results when baked with the wind, and a soft body simulation, which pushed the non-pinned cape away from the model but did not have the cape react as a cloth, just as a stiff object that translated across the view port. I feel like I am missing something more fundamental to this process, but I'm not sure what it is.

[image]

Comment: Hey there and welcome. As far as i can see in the vertex group list, you already have a group for the cape. If you create the inverted version of that or have one that essentially is the inverse of the cape, use that as pin group.

Comment: By inverted version, do you mean a vertex group that is weight painted all red except for the cape? Then do I pin it in the cloth simulation section "Shape" or soft body simulation section "Goal". I hear they give similar results.

Comment: Yes, as the cape vertex group is having the cape weighted as 1(red) if used as pin group the cape would not move, as it would be pinned. The pin-group will freeze the red or value 1 in place, values from 1-0 are gradually more affected. Inverted you get a red body, thus pinned/ignored by the cloth effect and the cape can freely flutter/drape or get sucked in a turbine :p. I'd leave softbody simulation for other things like a ball or pillow, but you are most certainly free to try. Though a cape is cloth after all.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! Okay so I made an inverted weight paint of the model with everything red except for the cape. I enabled collision and cloth on the mesh, with the inverted vertex group pinned under the "Shape" section. I added in a wind object in front of the model. When I bake, however, nothing changes and I don't see any simulation. I've been looking through various tutorials, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any pointers?

Comment: I would recommend to update/adjust your question with the end-goal of using wind to affect the cape. Add the new details in the question by using the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/177484/edit) function. I should have some time later to write an answer based on the mentioned details.

Comment: While i worked on the answer, i encountered a problem that necessitates a question. Can the cape on your character possibly be split at some sort of sewing line or is held in place with some sort of string around the neck. I created a simulation with a cape but with certain conditions. [Cape Sample](https://imgur.com/D0CDrXg). I could adjust it even better if you could share a deducted version of the scene. No armature, and only the cape and a part where it connects to the character would be enough to work with. You can use the [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Comment: I have uploaded a cloth test file with a cloth simulation on the character. As you can see it did not come out as expected :P. To answer your question, the cape is not connected to the character as a sewing line or a parented vertex group, it is apart of the mesh. Also the vertex group is a very rough weight paint, it is not characteristic of the full cape.

Comment: Well i believe you uploaded the file, but maybe forgot to add the link you get afterwards? You need to copy the questions address as the service is only for this forum. I'm sorry that i can't just write how to solve the situation, as there are so many possible start-criteria. That's also why i asked for the file. Else i could only make a guide how to add a cape to a stand-in body. But that solution may not be applicable for your situation.

Comment: I didn't get the embed code yet, it's a big file. Sorry about that and thanks for sticking around this long, I really appreciate it! Here's a Google Drive link to the file, hopefully this works better. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QTkHiiLwourdviObgqx9JrxhQJoq8e5Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Answer is up, took a bit longer then i thought and intended and i actually still want to add some small steps, but it should be enough to keep you busy for now. Also i added the final version as a dropbox link, since you didn't use the Blend-Exchange. If you do not have anything against me using it, i'd like to keep the answer and all it's related files in the forum connected services, so in that case just let me know, so i can adjust the link later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entire object, was in triangles which also were separated. A cloth simulation with this would never work to start with, neither would a soft-body simulation. Both are based on a interconnected structure/mesh.

Learning something new along the way, this is what i got, i hope it's somewhat close to your goal.
[image]

**Now regarding what is needed to get there**, or at least to a cape that simulates like cloth:
[image]

1. Since the entire object came triangulated and with all faces separate, we need to select the object, go in edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> first.
2. Now we can make the object a whole mesh by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> **(Merge) -> By Distance**
   [image]
3. Now the object can be separated into the two main parts, body and **cape**. For that we hover over a part of the cape and press <kbd>L</kbd> which will **Select Linked** vertices, thus the cape and the shoulder-part of it will be selected.
   [image]
4. To really separate the mesh into two objects we need to press <kbd>P</kbd>(Separate) and choose **Selection**. It will create a new object with the selected part.
   [image]
   *conveniently renamed the objects "body" and "cape"*
5. The separated objects allow for a much cleaner simulation, as the bigger the mesh simulated, the more calculations needed, but we are not yet done.
6. The cape can further be split in two parts, namely the shoulder-part and the cape itself. I'd recommend to hide(if not mentioned, hiding per outliner eye symbol) the body first.
7. Below a visual demonstration of the steps.
   [image]
   *Sideview makes it easier to select only the upper(shoulder) part. Important is to activate "X-Ray" <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to ensure the entire upper part is selected and not only the us facing part. Pressing <kbd>P</kbd> then allows for a separation based on "Selection"*
8. The new object will be the final cape(which we hide for now), the old cape becomes shoulders. And we are left with a hole at the bottom of the shoulders backside.
   [image]
   *Face Orientation overlay active here to make the hole easier to see (red is inside)*
9. I would clean up the shoulder parts geometry for a cleaner look, quads and such, but it's not needed for the simulation asked. Closing the hole we end up with this.
   [image]
   *The quads along the previous hole, will be used later as location for the pin-group of the cape.*
10. Since the shoulder part is done, we can switch to the cape geometry, as it needs some work before we can work with it. It's gonna be a bit more complicated, so i try to make **small steps**.
11. First hide the shoulder part, then make the cape visible, select it and go in the *vertex* edit mode.
12. We get rid of one side to reduce a lot of work. For that we go in the top view with <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> and activate **x-ray** with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
    [image]
13. Then select all vertices on one side of the y-axis and press <kbd>X</kbd> **Vertices**.
    [image]
14. Add a mirror modifier and select the Z-axis (situational, here it's Z).
    [image]
15. At this point the cape is not usable for simulation, as it has very odd density. So we need to clean this up. Starting with making the cape single-layered. Going along the outer border of the cape, this edge selection needs to be made.
    [image]
    [image]
    *We can see the cape as a 2 layered blanket, the outer is connected to the inner by a border, if we cut away at the border, the layers get structurally separated.*
16. With the border-loop selected we press <kbd>X</kbd> **Vertices**, to delete and at the same time separate the layers. With <kbd>L</kbd> (Select Linked) while hovering over a vertex of the left-over faces of the outer layer we select the now separate part(rest of the outer layer), which we then remove with <kbd>X</kbd> **Vertices**. A visual step by step demonstration below.
    [image]
17. We are now left with only one layer of faces for the cape, which needs some cleanup, manually with more control, but more time spend here a visual demonstration of some (not all, as repetitive) steps.
    [image]
    The cleaned up and remeshed cape could look something like this.
    [image]
    *Again, the settings for the Quad-remesher can be daunting, but results can be great*
18. The mesh having a better topology/density for cloth simulation makes the big difference. We now need to add the **pin-group** of the cape that will be responsible for fixing the cape to the shoulder-part.
    [image]
    *it's possible to add some weight to the sides of the cape going down to stiffen them a bit*
    [image]
    *visible in weight paint mode, the selected vertices can be **assigned** a lower value which will be added to the active vertex-group*
    [image]
19. Back in object mode, we add the cloth simulation to the cape.
20. Select the preset for **silk** and add the **pin-group** to the shape section.
    [image]
    *the values are the ones that worked for me.*
21. Finally make the body a collision object. And for later usage it's a good idea to make the body the parent of the shoulders and the shoulders parent of the cape.(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> object with the child and parent selected but the parent active)
    [image]
22. Lastly as already visible in later pictures, add a floor below the princess and make it an collision object as well. Also, wind, nearly forgot ..
23. The wind object was already in the scene, **BUT** it was too weak, and also not interesting enough, just like a hairdryer, on full throttle (still too weak).
24. So we are setting up the wind like this:
    [image]
    *steps should be easy to follow values can vary, but again these worked for me (may be a good starting point)*

The final result can be dissected here [Princess_with_cape](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kajo470yovn3lth/Princess_with_Cape.blend?dl=0)
(*I didn't use Blend-exchange as original owner did not use it either, should i get the ok, i'll change to Blend-Exchange*)

The cleanup steps i'm gonna add some more info later, hope in the meantime you can work with this.

Happy Blending

Comment: I actually have no words. I wish I could thank you in person, because this is genuinely fantastic. I'll work on this over the next couple days and I'll let you know if I have any questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have two quick questions, when separating the cape and shoulder parts, how do you do this, as they cannot be separated by P or selected with L individually. For steps 17 and 18, this deletes the vertices, so I am left with nothing in the view port, I'm not sure what you mean by outer and inner layers.

Comment: I updated the answer with more detailed steps and exchanged the pictures with gifs that show the steps in a more connected way. **Specifically 7. and 15.** Hope it's easier to understand now. Please check if it's answering your questions, should there still be unclear parts, don't hesitate to mention them.

Comment: Thank you! I just got it to work on my end with my armature and animation. I learned a lot from this, thank you very much. I hope this thread helps others who may be having similar problems, it's so in depth.

Comment: My pleasure. Would you kindly consider to accept the answer and may i ask if i can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) service to share the file, so it's kept stored in the same system as the forum uses?