# cloth floating effect? (Superman cape)

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

[image]

So above is what I am trying to do :

I am trying to make a cloth that stays at the same position but sort of waves very slowly like that superman cape is doing, so that it looks like its levitating.

Below is what I have made so far
[image]
[image]

I am trying to do so on the red cloth above, **but I made that with sculpting features.**
No simulation or physics are applied.

So I think that when I apply physics it wont work as expected and Ive never done cloth related simulations before so I have no idea where to start :(

Would there be any recommendations for getting that cape effect in the first gif?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177484/adding-cloth-physics-to-vertex-group   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93641/creating-looping-cloth-animation-for-sprite

Answer (score 3):

You could create a plane, subdivide, mask one of its ends, in *Sculpt* mode use the *Cloth Filter* brush / *Gravity* mode to already give it a cape look:

[image]

Then give your cape a *Cloth* physic, pin the same end edge, choose a very low *Speed Multiplier* value (like 0.1), enable *Self Collisions*, create a *Force Field > Wind*, give a *Strength* around 10 000:

[image]

Bake (here it is still a bit fast, my *Speed Multiplier* was at 0.2):

[image]

Comment: You only know this because you wear that cape all the time…

Comment: hey you swore not to tell my identity!

Comment: yeah...but honestly...you revealed yourself by this animation which is just a movie taken from your back with your iPhone. Everybody can see that this is NOT an animation.....!!!!‼️‼️‼️‼️ And only because you converted it to BW doesn't mean we don't see that....!!!

Comment: yes but Loïs asked me to spend less time on my computer

Comment: And she is right!!!! Listen to her!

Comment: to tell me that I suspect you're no other one than Lex Luthor  :((

Comment: I‘ll be back!